# how do I change the GROUPBY order in a histogram?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a dataframe that has 4 fields in it, **Responder**, **female**, **married**, and **children** which I plotted as a histogram.

```
import pandas as pd
data2= data1.groupby('Responder')
data3= data2['female','married','children'].mean()
data3.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Example of data]

As you can see in the output, it was grouped, which is what I wanted. The only thing I want to do now just have it so that each variable is grouped together. So for example you would have two blue bars for **female**, first one for N and second for Y. Then next to that, the N and Y bars for **married**, etc.

What is the syntax I need to do this?

[image: Histogram Output]

Comment: Could you post some example data from `data1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When plotting a DataFrame, each column becomes a legend entry, and each row becomes a horizontal axis category.

```
# Example data (different from yours):
df = pd.DataFrame({'Responder': ['Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
                   'female': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
                   'married': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
                   'children': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]})

g = df.groupby('Responder')
res = g.mean().T
res
Responder     N     Y
female     1.00  0.25
married    0.75  0.50
children   0.25  0.75

res.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Bar plot with swapped x-axis levels]

By the way, I'm not sure if `mean` is the correct choice here, since your original data consists of binary counts. Would a normalized sum make more sense?

Comment: Thank you Peter. What I did was to just add a .T at the end of data3= data2['female','married','children'].mean().  So I guess I just needed to transpose it. Thanks again!

Comment: @djacobs1216, you're right, in retrospect, the only required adjustment is a transpose :) you're welcome and happy coding!